# How Programatically Add 9 even images to a view |Swift

Tags: swift, uiimageview

I'm struggling with this one, hope to find any help with the code.
I'm trying to add programatically 9 images (3x3) which going to cover my whole UIView. 
my question is, how can i divide my UIView to 9 even images to cover it all, and consider there's different between the iPhones screen size.
I have no idea how to even start to customise it, just for example:

```
    firstImage.frame = CGRectMake(?,? ,200,200)
    secondImage.frame = CGRectMake(?,?, 200,200)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can divide the `view.frame` into a grid and add `UIImageView` as subviews at specific positions. The images are in an UIImage array.

```
func create(){
        //Divide the screen height and width /3 because 3*3
        var height = self.view.frame.height/3
        var width = self.view.frame.width/3
        //Add your images
        var imageArray:[UIImage] = [firstImage, secondImage]
        var count = 0
        for i in 0...2{
            for j in 0...2{
                //Add a subview at the position
                var subview = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(width*CGFloat(j), height*CGFloat(i), width, height))
                subview.image = imageArray[count]
                self.view.addSubview(subview)
                count++

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thnx man, it is math but i would never think about it myself ... I'm going to try it out